# Apache2 - Rewrite rule not working (Remote address)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Does anybody have any idea, why my rewrite rules in apache2 configuration are not working?

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.123\.121$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.107$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.17\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/html/$1

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/phones"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
</VirtualHost>
```

What I want to do is, that if clients from IP addresses 192.168.123.121, 192.168.1.107 or from network 10.17.x.x come to web server port 80, that they are redirected to different path (/var/www/html/) then all the other IP addreses (/var/www/html/phones/)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know multiple rewrite conditions with one rewrite rule are combined by a logical AND. Hence I would try the "or next condition" (OR) option:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.123\.121$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.107$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.17\.
```

BTW: Maybe it's helpful to activate logging, too. You can use something like

**Apache < 2.4**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

**Apache >= 2.4** (see further information about [logging in apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging))

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```

In the later case, you should pipe the log file through "fgrep" to find the interesting log entries. For example:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log | fgrep '[rewrite:'
```

You should *not* use this kind of logging in a production environment.